# MySQL c python (pyTel)

Tags: python, mysql, telebot, mysqlconnector

Доброго времени суток!
Пишу пошагового бота, который регистрирует анкету юзера.
  Имеется БД таблицей users в ней колонны: *name, city, age, sex, about, id, chat_id*(unique) 
По окончанию регистрации все веденные пользователем данные сохраняются в соответственные колонки. 
В колонку **chat_id** заносится ***уникальный* id**, который юзеру присвоил телеграмм.

После этого этапа есть кнопка "Заполнить анкету заново".
По задумке после нажатия на неё должна строка с данными юзера **удалялись** и перескакивало на первый этаж регистрации. Сделал записи 2-ух юзеров в БД и прописал удаление

```
        chat_id = message.from_user.id
        user = user_dict[chat_id]
        reset_profile = message.text
        if reset_profile == 'Заполнить анкету заново':
            chat_id = message.from_user.id
            user = user_dict[chat_id]
            sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = chat_id"

            mycursor.execute(sql)
            mydb.commit()
            print(mycursor.rowcount, "record(s) deleted")
            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хорошо\nЗаполним анкету заново\nКак твоё имя?")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_name_step)
```

Если прописываю `DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = chat_id` , то удаляется **не одна строка(записи)** из таблицы users, **а все** и просить заново пройти анкету...
Не могу понять как передать в `chat_id =`  тот самый уникальный id юзера, который заполняет анкету.
По-разному пробовал - не выходит
Тестирую через свой телеграмм и внесением в бд юзера
 `sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, city, age, sex, about, chat_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`"
`val = ("тест", "тест", "20", "Парень", "информация", 123456)`
Прошу помощи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = chat_id"
```

Данный запрос означает что вы берете строку из таблицы где chat_id = chat_id, а он будет равен ему всегда. Чтобы такого не было, нужно передавать в запрос chat_id из python кода, с которым он будет сравниваться, для этого используется %s. В вашем случае будет что-то подобное:

```
sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = %s"
mycursor.execute(sql, (chat_id,))
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное тебе! Можете еще разъяснить почему в `(chat_id,))` как именно эта конструкция работает и почему нужна запятая? Где-то может прочитать можно

Comment: Точно не скажу, она нужна если передаете только одну переменную. Скорее всего без этой запятой кортеж преобразуется в строку и не может быть подставлен в запрос

Answer (score 0):

Строка `sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = chat_id"` воспринимается дословно, без передачи туда параметров (Вы же их не передаете). По сути запрос звучит так - удали все строки где поле чат_ид = полю чат_ид и, что логично, удаляет все)

Вам нужно передать параметры

```
sql = text("DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = :chat_id")
mycursor.execute(sql, chat_id = <переменная_с_идентификатором_чата>)
```

Comment: получается надо так написать? `sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE chat_id = :chat_id" `   ниже строка `mycursor.execute(sql, chat_id =message.from_user.id)` Или я чего не могу понять(

Comment: да, либо вместо `message.from_user.id` переменную `chat_id` которую Вы объявили выше

Comment: к сожалению не сработало. Я не понимаю почему =\ Может еще какие-нибудь варианты есть?

Comment: Очень надеюсь на Вашу помощь :)

Comment: @Alexeevich покажите как Вы объявляете курсор, какая библиотека

Comment: `mycursor = mydb.cursor()` объявляю так, использую mysql.connector. Если отправить напрямую запрос `sql = "delete from users where chat_id = %s"` `val = (_чат айди_) ` , то работает(

Comment: @Alexeevich особенности разных драйверов)

Comment: так почему же предложенное Вами решение не работает, по идее должно же... Что можете посоветовать? Я недавно начал всё это изучать

Comment: @Alexeevich Я же говорю, в зависимости от того какую библиотеку используете. Посоветовать - ознакомление с документациями